# Pre insert data when adding new custom post fire a json error

Tags: json, wp-insert-post, save-post

here is what i have tried

```
function mec_locations_cpt_add_content ( $data, $postarr) {        //, $postarr
    if ( 'mec_locations_cpt' !== $postarr['post_type'] ) {
         return $data;
    }
    if ( 'publish' !== $postarr['post_status'] ) {
         return $data;
    }
    $post = get_post( $postarr['ID'] );
    //$mec_location_shortcode='[mec-location id=”{LOCATION_ID}” limit_events=”{NUMBER}”]';        //to get from an admin field
    //$mec_location_shortcode ='<!-- wp:shortcode -->[mec-location id=128]<!-- /wp:shortcode -->';
    $data['post_content'] .= '<!-- wp:shortcode -->[mec-location id=128]<!-- /wp:shortcode -->';
    $data['post_content'] .= '<!-- wp:paragraph -->#####################################################'.'post='.print_r($post,true).'<!-- /wp:paragraph -->';
    $data['post_content'] .= '<!-- wp:paragraph -->@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'.'data='.print_r($data,true).'<!-- /wp:paragraph -->';
    $data['post_content'] .= '<!-- wp:paragraph -->&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'.'postarr='.print_r($postarr,true).'<!-- /wp:paragraph -->';
    //$data['post_title']   .= 'some text';
    //$data['post_excerpt']  = 'This is my excerpt inserted for new post';
    // If value is not in content, append it onto the end
    //if ( stristr( $data['post_content'], $content_shortcode ) === FALSE ) $data['post_content'] .= 'add this'.$meta_value .($meta_value);
    //$postarr['post_title'] .='add some text';
    //$postarr['post_content'] .='ok ! added ' . $mec_location_shortcode;
    //$postarr['post_excerpt']  ='My new updated excerpt';
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'mec_locations_cpt_add_content' ,100 ,2);
```

but asap i try to add a new post, i have an error message
La sauvegarde de cet article dans votre navigateur est différente de la version ci-dessous.
meaning ~ : the post is diferent than the one in browser

when i edit title and content and try to publish the post it give a json error
La publication a échoué. La réponse n’est pas une réponse JSON valide.
I have tried to change permalink setting with no success
i get the same error without adding any content

but the strange is if i cancel publish the post is saved in db and the array are included twice...
if i edit again the post, it fires again a json error but the post content is updated again

Does it mean that wp_insert_post_data is fired before insert and again at the save_post ????

i know that making it this way will add content each time. i planed to add some check content before adding it but for now i try to remove only the error message

Answer (score 0):

You should use content_save_pre filter. And maybe try some "simple" content first.

wp_insert_post_data is fired in a lot of situations :-) Even at deleting.

Comment: hi, i will try rewrite using it as it seems i will not be able to use wp_insert_post_data. but i don't undestand why it make this json error when i only try to add a basic and "simple" word like just "hello" in content